# Sql Subquery Question

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table of data that contains 3 columns that refer to the id's of another table.

table1:
`id`, `person1_id`, `person2_id`, `person3_id`

people:
`id`, `fname`, `lname`

what is the most efficient way of returning `fname` and instead of `person1_id` in my query?

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you are trying to query?  If you have the id of table 1, do you want the value of data1 in table2?

Comment: i edited my question with more specific details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  x.fname,
  y.fname,
  z.fname
FROM
  table1 a
  INNER JOIN people x ON x.id = a.person1_id
  INNER JOIN people y ON y.id = a.person2_id
  INNER JOIN people z ON z.id = a.person3_id
```

Comment: This was exactly what i needed, efficient too

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood the question well, but:

```
SELECT table2.data1 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 WHERE table1.o1=table2.id
```

Comment: that works, but it will only pull the first person's name, i also need the name of person2 and person3

Comment: I've found that explicit joins cause less confusion.  I would write the above as: SELECT table2.data1 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.o1 = table2.id

Comment: Just add "OR" clauses to get the name of person2 and person3.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess about how you want the data formatted, but it sounds like for every record in table1, you want to replace the ID with the first name from the people table.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  (SELECT fname FROM people WHERE id = person1_id) as Person1_fname,
  (SELECT fname FROM people WHERE id = person2_id) as Person2_fname,
  (SELECT fname FROM people WHERE id = person3_id) as Person3_fname
FROM
  table1
```

This will give you all of the records in table1 and 'replace' the id's with the first names, like so:

```
1, George, Chris, Judy
2, Sam, Jennifer, Sara
```

With a table1 of

```
1, 1, 2, 3
2, 4, 5, 6
```

and a people table of

```
1, George, Carlin
2, Chris, Rock
3, Judy, Smith
4, Sam, Elliot
5, Jennifer, Garner
6, Sara, Johnson
```

I'm assuming there is a unique constraint on people.id as well.  If not, you'll want to put a TOP 1 before fname in the 3 field queries.

Comment: It isn't very effective way to do this - better use JOINs because of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this:

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.data1 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.o1 = table2.id;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help you. i taken table1 as sample

```
SELECT sample.*,person.fname,p.fname FROM sample left join person on sample.p1=person.id, sample s left join person p on s.p2=p.id group by sample.id
```